# Angular 7/8 - How the content get refreshed automatically

Tags: angular

While doing a simple hello world application Angular today ,  i could see the output get immediately/simultaneously update while typing itself , without even referring the browser page.

https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_default

For example :If we take above URL , While typing something in text box, it gets append to the word "Hello" in a instant way. Where as in html,dot net, jquery or etc,. we need to refresh the page or trigger a event to do this, how can angular do this ?

Comment: What do you mean "output gets immediately updated while typing"? There are many reasons why DOM can be updated and I am not sure it is related to angular

Comment: has updated the question for better under standing

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with Angular's change detection. Read more about it [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/).